# how to get last inserted row in core data swift4

Tags: core-data, swift3

I am trying to get the row that is inserted latest

This is the code I have written

```
let context = coreData.getContext()
let request:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest() request.entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Days", in: context)

let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "day_id", ascending: false)
request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
request.fetchLimit = 1
```

I have written `ascending:false` as well and to fetch the row

```
let result1 = try context.fetch(request)
for r in result1{
    print(r)
}
```

But it doesn't retrieve the last inserted row. What am I missing?

Comment: What is `day_id`?

Comment: unique id that I have managed to create through code

Comment: This `id` must be sortable and the values must be assigned ascending then the code  should work.

Comment: Exactly, but it doesn't get me the last row, instead, it gives me first inserted row\

Comment: Maybe the order is not ascending. Try `..., ascending: true`. Is the format of the `id` really sortable reliably?

Comment: In your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565685/checking-if-a-row-is-present-in-core-data-swift4) you had an issue when fetching an object for a given day_id. Are you sure there's not a problem with day_id or the coreData.getContext() method?